# Different result in Protege 4.3 and result in jena in Eclipse

Tags: rdf, jena, owl, protege, protege4

In Protégé 4.3 I have results with ObjectProperties (exactly as I need).
But I need to implement it in my project so I use Jena in Eclipse and the result is different.
How can I get object with ObjectProperties in Jena?

**Protégé:**
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLpCD.png]

**Eclipse Jena:**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | 
subject                                | object                     
|
=============================================================================== | vidlica:VidlicaKrytTelo                | _:b0                       
| | vidlica:KolikNulovy_SkrutkaM3          | _:b1                     
| | vidlica:KolikFazovy_SkrutkaM3          | _:b2                     
| | vidlica:Hlava_4Kolik_SkrutkaM3_Nalepka | _:b3                     
| | vidlica:Hlava_4Kolik_SkrutkaM3         | _:b4                     
| | vidlica:Final                          | _:b5                     
| | _:b5                                   | vidlica:Final            
| | _:b4                                   |
vidlica:Hlava_4Kolik_SkrutkaM3         | | _:b2                       
| vidlica:KolikFazovy_SkrutkaM3          | | _:b3                     
| vidlica:Hlava_4Kolik_SkrutkaM3_Nalepka | | _:b1                     
| vidlica:KolikNulovy_SkrutkaM3          | | _:b0                     
| vidlica:VidlicaKrytTelo                | | vidlica:TesnenieGumove   
| vidlica:TesnenieGumove                 | | rdf:List                 
| rdf:List                               | | _:b6                     
| _:b6                                   | | _:b7                     
| _:b7                                   | | owl:Restriction
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.  What are you doing to get the results that we're seeing from Protégé, and what did you do to get the results from Jena?  Are you running a SPARQL query?  What's the code that did this?

Comment: Q was simple: "How can I get object with ObjectProperties in Jena?"

Comment: But during time I found solution. The "_:bx" are "Blank nodes" -> [info](http://web.ing.puc.cl/~marenas/publications/iswc11.pdf) <-
and to select triple in SPARQL we need to work with blank nodes, coz Object properties and some others axioms are not relevant part of triple patern.
If someone need more info in future ... mail me ;)

Comment: I still don't know exactly what you were asking; if you just want to list the properties used in a model you could just use [listStatements](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/ModelCon.html#listStatements(com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource,%20com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property,%20java.lang.String)) to iterate through the triples in a model and build a set of the properties. At any rate, if you solved the problem, please post your solution as an answer, so that others who come across this question can benefit, too!

Comment: I was asking for query to get tripple with object property.

Comment: You say that you're asking for "triples with object properties".  Triples are an RDF-level representation, which means that the RDF serialization of an OWL ontology will contains lots of triples that you might not be interested in (e.g., the triples with blank nodes, as you've noted above).  I zoomed in on your picture, and what you're actually showing there is "subject" and "object", and the objects appear to be class expressions of the form "property **some** class-expression".  This suggests that you actually asked for triples of the form "?subject rdf:type ?object".  However, …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no prob to write down some code as answer, but its hard to write it clear and easy to understand.

One more time: I ask how to get in jena sparql result like this
object + object property + subject(s) [ C2-C4].

And the result is (this sample with 3 subjects)

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?c ?p1 ?C2 ?C3 ?C4
WHERE { 
    ?c rdfs:subClassOf ?r . 
    ?r rdf:type owl:Restriction . 
    ?r owl:onProperty ?p1 . 
    ?r owl:someValuesFrom ?i . 
    ?i rdf:type owl:Class . 
    ?i ?prop ?l . 
    ?l rdf:first ?C2 . 
    ?l rdf:rest ?m . 
    ?m rdf:first ?C3 . 
    ?m rdf:rest ?m2 . 
    ?m2 rdf:first ?C4 . 
    ?m2 rdf:rest rdf:nil .
    }
```